ModuleNotFoundError when importing module from subpackage in Python
I have a Python project structured as follows:
projectX/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── functions/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello.py
└── test/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py

from main.py I can import the hello.py module without any issues: from functions.hello import greet
from test.py, I'm trying to import the module hello.py with the statement: from functions.hello import greet but I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
My init.py modules are just empty .py scripts
I've tried using relative paths from ..functions.hello import greet which gives the following error: attempted relative import with no known parent package
I've also attempted to modify the sys.path in test.py to include the parent directory of my project using the following code: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
I've visited the following SO questions but I'm still confused as to how you make this import work: Relative imports for the billionth time

"I've visited the following SO questions but I'm still confused as to how you make this import work: Relative imports for the billionth time" - it's called "... for the billionth time" for a reason. There isn't anything else that can really be explained about them. But you started out by asking about how to make an absolute import work. You need to pick one to have a suitable question - and both are common duplicates.

To make the absolute import work, as explained in the duplicate I've chosen, functions has to be in a place that Python will look when it searches for modules (the paths listed on sys.path). It may or may not be on the path, depending on how you start Python (as well as any explicit changes made later) - it does not depend on which file contains the import statement (that would be a relative import, and that's the "relative" thing about them). But if you started the program from test.py, starting in that folder, that would impact on what sys.path contains.

"I've also attempted to modify the sys.path in test.py to include the parent directory of my project using the following code: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))" - okay, and what happened when you tried this? That is one of the standard approaches (although IMO it is usually grossly unnecessary), and we can't tell you any more about it - if it didn't work for you, then you simply didn't do it right, and we can really only copy and paste the same instructions back at you.

Did you make sure to do this before the import is attempted? Did you try to check what sys.path contains, or do any other debugging?
